# Next.js API route error on Vercel - Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, vercel

The code works perfectly fine on my local machine using a development server, but on the deployed version on Vercel, the API route call always fails. For reference, I am on an M1 MacBook Air, 16 GB unified memory.

Here is the code for the API route:

```js
import { openai } from "@/openai.config";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { ChatCompletionRequestMessage } from "openai";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return res.status(405).json({ error: "METHOD NOT ALLOWED" });
  } else {
    const { category, country, isRemote, businessSize } = req.body.params;
    const prompt: ChatCompletionRequestMessage[] = [
      {
        role: "user",
        content: `Give me only ONE unique and innovative ${
          businessSize == 0
            ? "small-sized"
            : businessSize == 1
            ? "medium-sized"
            : "large-sized"
        } business idea for the ${category} industry, closely tailored for the local requirements, consumer psyche, culture, and market conditions of ${country}. ${
          isRemote
            ? "It should be possible to operate this business completely remotely."
            : ""
        } I want you to format your answer in strictly three lines this format: \nSuggested name of the business\nDescription of the business\nA strictly JavaScript array of possible domain names`,
      },
    ];
    await openai
      .createChatCompletion({
        model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages: prompt,
      })
      .then((completion) => {
        console.log(completion.data.choices[0].message?.content);
        const response =
          completion.data.choices[0].message?.content?.split("\n");
        if (response != undefined) {
          // console.log(response[2]?.substring(response[2].indexOf(":") + 1));
          const businessName = response[0]
            ?.substring(response[0].indexOf(":") + 1)
            .replace(/"/g, "");
          const businessDescription = response[1]?.substring(
            response[1].indexOf(":") + 1
          );
          let businessDomainsString = response[2]?.substring(
            response[2].indexOf(":") + 1
          );
          businessDomainsString.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "");
          businessDomainsString = businessDomainsString
            .trim()
            .slice(1, -1)
            .replace(/'/g, "");
          const businessDomains = businessDomainsString.split(",");

          res.status(200).json({
            businessName: businessName,
            businessDescription: businessDescription,
            businessDomains: businessDomains,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR" });
      });
  }
}
```

This is the link to the production build, hosted on Vercel - https://turbobiz.viditkhandelwal.com

This is the error I get in the Serverless Function logs on Vercel -

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":
"Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/var/task/node_modules
/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index.js'","reason":
{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"EMFILE: too many open files, open
'/var/task/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index.js'","code":"EMFILE","errno":-24,"syscall":"open","path":"
/var/task/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index.js","stack":
["Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/var/task/node_modules
/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index.js'"," at Object.openSync
(node:fs:601:3)"," at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)"," at
 Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)","
 at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)"," at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)"," at
 ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)"," at
 ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules
/esm/module_job:194:25)"]},"promise":{},"stack":
["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: EMFILE: too many open
 files, open '/var/task/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-
esm/index.js'"," at process. (file:///var/runtime
/index.mjs:1189:17)"," at process.emit (node:events:525:35)"," at emit
 (node:internal/process/promises:149:20)"," at
 processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:283:27)","
 at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process
/task_queues:96:32)"]} Unknown application error occurred
 Runtime.Unknown
```

I have spent 4 hours searching for fixes, but nothing has worked yet. Let me know if you need any more information or context.

I have already made sure that all external API calls (both OpenAI and Firebase) are followed by `then()` and `catch()` expressions so that no promise is unresolved, both on the client and server-side. Since the code works fine on my machine, and the app is quite lightweight, I am not sure why this error should occur.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, [do not require the reader to use links to external information](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/more-advice#dont-require-external-and-off-site-resources). Everything should be in the question itself. If you have code, copy and paste it into the question so it's easy to read, copy, and search.